# Compile gRPC with OpenSSL on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl, grpc

I have compile and install OpenSSL on Windows at a standard location (C:\Program Files\OpenSSL) and here's my build.bat file to compile gRPC:

```
setlocal
@call  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"

if not exist build mkdir build2
if not exist install mkdir install
rmdir /S /Q dist
mkdir dist

cmake . -B build2 -A x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B 1

cmake --build build2 --config Release
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B 1

cmake --install build2
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B 1

tar -C install -czf dist/gRPC.tar.gz .
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B 1
```

However, it seems like that is not working as CMake cannot find the OpenSSL header:

```
...
C:\Users\atran\Desktop\source_code\grpc\src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.h(24,10): fatal error C1083: Canno
t open include file: 'openssl/x509.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\atran\Desktop\source_code\grpc\buil
d2\grpc.vcxproj]
  xds_cluster_impl.cc
C:\Users\atran\Desktop\source_code\grpc\third_party\upb\upb/table_internal.h(200,28): warning C4334: '<<': res
ult of 32-bit shift implicitly converted to 64 bits (was 64-bit shift intended?) [C:\Users\atran\Desktop\sourc
e_code\grpc\build2\grpc.vcxproj]
C:\Users\atran\Desktop\source_code\grpc\third_party\upb\upb/msg_internal.h(469,40): warning C4334: '<<': resul 
t of 32-bit shift implicitly converted to 64 bits (was 64-bit shift intended?) [C:\Users\atran\Desktop\source_ 
code\grpc\build2\grpc.vcxproj]
C:\Users\atran\Desktop\source_code\grpc\src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.h(24,10): fatal error C1083: Canno
t open include file: 'openssl/x509.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\atran\Desktop\source_code\grpc\buil
d2\grpc.vcxproj]
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It smells like your OpenSSL installation misses the header `openssl/x509.h`. It could be too old.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, turned out the problem for this is because I forgot to do CMake on a clean directory and therefore many of the CMake artifacts from previous attempts made it into this one.